# Confused When Filter is evaluate In angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

**FIlter In Template**

**Using a filter in a view template will reevaluate the filter on every digest** From angular document.

Even when the value of expression is not changing still it is reevaluating(or say input to filter is not changing). What i know  for each expression some watcher will be set. During digest loop it will check for any change in expression value if yes than it will fire watcher. And expression will be reevaluate.But why filter is reevaluate on every digest even when input is not changing.

**The filter function should be a pure function, which means that it should be stateless and idempotent. Angular relies on these properties and executes the filter only when the inputs to the function change.**
From angular doc.

Earlier it say it will revaluate on every digest in second bold text they say whenever input change.What is the diffference between two. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

**Update**

I made reveraFilter

app.js File

```
angular.module('todoApp')
    .filter('reversa', function() {
        return function(input, condition) {
            input = input || '';
            var out = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                out = input.charAt(i) + out;
            }
            return out;
        };
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, reversaFilter) {


        $scope.todo = '';
        $scope.text = 'shriyansh';
        //  $scope.text = reversaFilter($scope.text);


    });
```

Partial HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>My todos</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="todo">
    <div>{{text|reversa}}</div>
</div>
```

I put breakpoint inside return functon of filter.
When ever I am changing value of todo variable it is execution filter code also. But I put filter to text not to todo.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular `$digest()` loop is a special mechanism which Angular is able to use to provide the Two-Way binding capabilities that are one of it's signature features.

Essentially, angular creates a `$watch()` for every variable which is used in an expression or filter.  Whenever any watched item changes, the `$digest()` loop fires, and evaluates all the properties on the scope.  During the `$digest`, expressions are re-evaluated, filters are re-calculated, and the DOM is updated to reflect any changes.

If the change in one variable triggers a different variable to change (for example: `{{a + b = c}}` would cause `c` to change if `a` or `b` were changed), the change to the second variable triggers a new `$digest` to occur, to evaluate if those changes would impact any other variables, and so on.  The `$digest` loop is only "stable" once there are no further changes to the variables being watched.

Filters have to be re-evaluated in this `$digest` loop as well, since it is possible that one of the changes could be to the way the filter is sorted, the parameters being used in the filter, or even the actual list being filtered.  If the `$digest` loop did not handle these possibilities, then the filter would not be able to react to the Two-Way binding in a fluid manner.

This is where it becomes important that filter functions are **idempotent**.  If the filter has side effects, these side effects could put the `$digest` into an endless loop.  The `$digest` cycle could be caught in a position where every change causes another change which causes another change, perpetually.

The `$digest` loop has a breakout point, and will throw an error `10 iterations reached` and will cease to continue processing if it encounters this potential endless loop.  Also, in an attempt to further keep this from being an issue, the filter ***function itself*** is only executed if the inputs change.  So while the filter is being *evaluated*, it is not being *executed* every cycle, unless it is necessary.

Comment: Claies reevaluated means checking for wheather that expression changed or not.

Comment: Yes, but that is the point, a filter function is not an expression, and angular assumes that they have no effect on other values, they strictly modify how the already evaluated input is displayed.